# Hardhat says it deployed contract to 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3?

Tags: hardhat

No matter what I seem to put in my hardhat.config.js, my contract gets deployed to 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3. What am I doing wrong?

```
PRIVATE_KEY=[redacted] node scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
deploying...
awaiting disperse.deployed()
Disperse deployed to: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
```

My `hardhat.config.js` is pretty basic, it just contains this for the networks:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: "https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_goerli",
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    },
    sepolia: {
      url: "https://rpc.sepolia.org",
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  },
  ...
```

My deployment script is also pretty straightforward, it contains:

```
  const Disperse = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("DisperseNft");
  console.log("deploying...")
  const disperse = await Disperse.deploy();

  console.log("awaiting disperse.deployed()")
  await disperse.deployed();

  console.log("Disperse deployed to:", disperse.address);
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to fix this, though I have no idea why this works.

Instead of running

```
node scripts/deploy.js
```

run

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to deploy the contract on any of the testnet/mainnet then please provide --network "testnet/mainnet" along the command. Example

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with:

```
npx run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia.
```

I forgot to add the `hardhat` command in. It should be:

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
```